# Macro : How to output a comma in a backquoted generated code?

Tags: common-lisp

I have a macro of the form:

```lisp
;; Macro which does a sort of defun for instance, with some other stuff.
(defmacro def2 (name (&rest args) &body body)
  `(defun ,(intern (string-upcase name)) (,@args)
     ,@body))
```

And I want to generate lots of `def2` :

```lisp
(defmacro defdefs ()
  `(progn
     ,@(loop for name in '("name1" "name2" "name3")
         collect `(def2 ,name (&rest args)
            (print ,@args))))) ; <---- HERE.
```

I want to refer to the `args` in the `def2` form, but if I write `,@args` it will refer to a variable (not defined) in `defdefs` macro.
I have thought to use something like `macro-function` and `apply` but is there a better way to tell `defdefs` that I want to output this list :
`(print ,@args)` without evaluating the `,@args` part during macroexpansion?

I have tried to play with quotes, double quotes, backquotes and double backquotes but I cannot find a solution...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CL-USER 33 > (defmacro def2 (name (&rest args) &body body)
               `(defun ,(intern (string-upcase name)) (,@args)
                  ,@body))
DEF2

CL-USER 34 > (defmacro defdefs ()
               `(progn
                  ,@(loop for name in '("name1" "name2" "name3")
                          collect `(def2 ,name (&rest args)
                                     (print args)))))
DEFDEFS

CL-USER 35 > (pprint (macroexpand '(defdefs)))

(PROGN
  (DEF2 "name1" (&REST ARGS) (PRINT ARGS))
  (DEF2 "name2" (&REST ARGS) (PRINT ARGS))
  (DEF2 "name3" (&REST ARGS) (PRINT ARGS)))

CL-USER 36 > (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(DEF2 "name1" (&REST ARGS) (PRINT ARGS))))

(DEFUN NAME1 (&REST ARGS)
  (PRINT ARGS))
```

Comment: Thank you. :) It is indeed exact, but I think I've given a bad formulation to my question (it works this way with `print`, a poor choice of function). If I want to use a function with &rest arguments instead of `print`, for example `(list ,@args)`, how can I do it ?

Comment: @Fnifni  `(apply #'list args)`